# React: how to prevent infinite loop and redirect to the just created resource

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

The code attached causes an infinite redirect loop (maybe due the fact I call `this.setState()` inside `onCreateMyResource()`?).

**My goal is to redirect the browser to the URL of the just created resource.**

I'm using `"react-router-dom": "^6.8.1"`.

To create the resource, the user goes to the page `/my-resources/`.

Once created, I want the browser redirect to `/my-resources/1234`, where `1234` is the ID of the just created resource.

With this code, the browser is correctly redirected to the route of the just created resource, but, then, it starts to redirect indefinitely:

[image]

[image]

*The two images represent what's reported in the dev console: after a lot of redirections, the warning "Warning: Maximum update depth exceeded." appears, then the redirection loop starts again and, again, after a lot of redirections, the warning is fired. Then the loop starts over, with a lot of redirections and warnings, indefinitely, without never stopping.*

The redirect, then, seems to also cause an infinite call to `setState()` (or viceversa: the infinite loop calling `setState()` causes the inifite redirect loop, I don't know nor well understand what's going on).

How can I do this avoiding the infinite loop?

**Maybe my approach is completely wrong**, but I cannot think at another possible way.

Any ideas?

Thank you in advance!

## The component `DetailsView`

```js
import { MY_RESOURCE_KEY } from 'MyResources/config/myResources';
import Form from 'MyResources/components/Details/Form';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { createMyResourceThunk } from 'MyResources/actions/create';
import { updateMyResourceThunk } from 'MyResources/actions/update';
import MyResource from 'MyResources/models/MyResource';
import { dbGetMyResourceModelFromId } from 'MyResources/selectors/myResources';
import withRouter, {
  shape as routerShape,
} from 'App/Core/integrations/packages/react-router-dom/withRouter';
import { ACCOUNT_KEY } from 'Accounts/config/accounts';
import { extractIdFromIri } from 'App/Utilities/fetch';
import { Navigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import { ACCOUNT_ENDPOINT } from 'Accounts/config/accounts';

class DetailsView extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { hasToRedirectAsCreated: null };
    this.onCreateMyResource = this.onCreateMyResource.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const { myResourceModel } = this.props;
    const { hasToRedirectAsCreated } = this.state;

    console.log(myResourceModel);
    console.log(hasToRedirectAsCreated);

    if (myResourceModel && myResourceModel.id === hasToRedirectAsCreated) {
      this.setState({ hasToRedirectAsCreated: null });
    }
  }

  onCreateMyResource(formFields) {
    const { accountId, onCreate } = this.props;
    onCreate(accountId, formFields).then((iri) => {
      const id = extractIdFromIri(iri);

      this.setState({ hasToRedirectAsCreated: id });
    });
  }

  render() {
    const { accountId, myResourceModel, onUpdate } = this.props;
    const {hasToRedirectAsCreated} = this.state;

    if (null !== hasToRedirectAsCreated) {
      return <Navigate to={`/${ACCOUNT_ENDPOINT}/${accountId}/my-resources/${hasToRedirectAsCreated}`} replace={true} />;
    }

    return (
      <div id="MyResourceDetails">
        <Form
          // We pass the full object as it is required for the deletion
          myResourceModel={myResourceModel}
          onSubmit={myResourceModel ? onUpdate : this.onCreateMyResource}
          initialValues={myResourceModel}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

DetailsView.propTypes = {
  accountId: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  onCreate: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  onUpdate: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  myResourceModel: PropTypes.shape(MyResource.propShape),
  route: PropTypes.shape(routerShape).isRequired,
};

DetailsView.defaultProps = { myResourceModel: MyResource.defaultProps };

const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => {
  const myResourceId = ownProps.route.params[MY_RESOURCE_KEY];
  let myResourceModel = null;

  if (null !== myResourceId) {
    myResourceModel = dbGetMyResourceModelFromId(state, myResourceId);
  }

  return {
    accountId: ownProps.route.params[ACCOUNT_KEY],
    myResourceModel: myResourceModel,
  }
};

const mapDispatchToProps = {
  onCreate: createMyResourceThunk,
  onUpdate: updateMyResourceThunk,
};

export default withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(DetailsView));
```

### How the component is rendered from the routes

This is the component that manages the routes:

```
class MyApp extends React.Component {

  render() {
    const { isCurrentAccountSet, isLoadingAccounts } = this.props;
    const isLoading = false === isCurrentAccountSet || true === isLoadingAccounts;

    return (
      <Router>
        <div id="Main">
          <Header isLoading={isLoading} />
            ...
            <Route
              path="/accounts/:account/my-resources/:myResource?"
              element={isLoading ? <LoadingAccounts /> : <MyResourcesPage />}
            />
            ...
          </Routes>
        </div>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}
```

This is the component `MyResourcesPage` that then renders `DetailsView`:

```
class MyResourcesPage extends React.Component {

  componentDidMount() {
    const { accountId, listMyResources } = this.props;
    listMyResources(accountId);
  }

  render() {
    const { accountId, myResourceId, isLoading } = this.props;

    return (
      <div className="container">
        <div className="row">
          <div className="col-sm-4">
            <div className="Page boxed rounded">
              {!isLoading && <ButtonNew accountId={accountId} />}
              {isLoading ? <Loader /> : <List accountId={accountId} myResourceId={myResourceId} />}
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="col-sm-8">
            <div className="Page boxed rounded">
              <DetailsView myResourceId={myResourceId} />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: What or where do you suspect the render looping is occurring? Can you [edit] to share more of the router and routes?

Comment: First of all, than you for your comment. I have updated the question with more details and screenshots. I don't understand what you would like to see when you write "more of the router and routes": maybe you would like to see how I configured the routes?

Comment: I'm assuming this component is rendered on a route? I'm also assuming that the component may also be getting *remounted* if the `componentDidMount` lifecycle is getting repeated called. Seeing how this component is rendered, and seeing what it is navigating to may help. Yes, I would like to see how you configured the routes.

Comment: The component is rendered by a `MyResourcePage` component. This component renders a two columns page: on the left, `MyResourcePage` renders the list of resources already present in DB; on the right, `MyResourcePage` renders the component `DetailsView` of which I posted the code. It's a bit tricky to post the configuration of routes, but, give me some time and I'll post it...

Comment: Question updated with more details about the routes are handled...

Comment: This is a bit of code to read through, and it's also a bit convoluted, is it really the minimal code necessary to reproduce the issue? Could you [edit] the post to describe what the behavior should be and walk us through the reproduction steps one-by-one? Perhaps try creating a ***running* [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) demo that reproduces the issue that we could inspect live?

Comment: What the bahaviour should be is described in the second line: "My goal is to redirect the browser to the URL of the just created resource.". This is really the minimal code... Unfortunately I don't know how to reproduce the issue on Codesandbox :(

Answer (score 0):

Feels like it might be in the `componentDidMount`.

Can you try:

```
componentDidMount() {
  const { myResourceModel } = this.props;
  const { hasToRedirectAsCreated } = this.state;

  console.log(myResourceModel);
  console.log(hasToRedirectAsCreated);

  if (myResourceModel && hasToRedirectAsCreated === myResourceModel.id) {
    this.setState({ hasToRedirectAsCreated: null });
  }
}
```

Comment: Sorry: in the various copy and paste I did to create the question, I shuld have forgotten a wrong code. The original code already has `hasToRedirectAsCreated === myResourceModel.id` (while it hadn't `if (myResourceModel &&` and I edited the code to simply use `myResourceModel`). I'm going to enrich the question with more details... In the meantime, many thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.

I moved the login to nullify `hasToRedirectAsCreated` from `componentDidMount()` to `componentDidUpdate()` and now the infinite redirection loop is gone.